# Disable Browser popup blocker in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, popupwindow

I need to open a new window using jquery but, it gets stuck with popup blocker in the Browser. How to disable or override it using jquery.
Heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.open('http://yahoo.in');

    });
```

please help me. Thanks

Comment: If you could override the popup blocker, so could the malware that it's designed to protect against. So you can't.

Comment: Popup blockers generally tend to allow same-domain windows. I assume yours is cross-domain? If so, then there's not much you can do as @Barmar says.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar

Comment: Thanks for the help @RoryMcCrossan